# How to translate the value of time_ago_in_words func to my language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made an Arabic Web-App using Ruby on Rails, how can i convert the result of time_ago_in_words function to Arabic Language?

or should I write my own function?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) method's docs, which uses under the hood of [`time_ago_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words), you will see, that you can pass a `scope` option for custom translation lookup:

> With the `scope` option, you can define a custom scope for Rails to look
>   up the translation.
>
> For example you can define the following in your locale (e.g. en.yml).
>
> ```
> datetime:
>   distance_in_words:
>     short:
>       about_x_hours:
>         one: 'an hour'
>         other: '%{count} hours'
> ```
>
> See github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml for
>   more examples.
>
> Which will then result in the following:
>
> ```
> from_time = Time.now distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 50.minutes, scope: 'datetime.distance_in_words.short')
> # => "an hour"
> distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, from_time + 3.hours, scope: 'datetime.distance_in_words.short')
> # => "3 hours"
> ```